# How to add references to IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON MEDICAL IMAGING

Tags: templates, ieee, ieeecolor

I'm planning to submit a paper to IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON MEDICAL IMAGING. To do this I first found the appropriate latex template here: https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/downloadTemplate?publicationTypeId=1&titleId=4&articleId=1&fileId=4

Then I uploaded this to overleaf. Now I want to add references but the example template doesn't show how to incorporate a BibTeX file. Here they hard code the references in a "\begin{thebibliography}{00}" section. Is there any way I can incorporate a bibtex file with the required format since this document has a class of ieeecolor. Typing out so many references by hand seems very time consuming.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You can almost certainly use BibTeX in the same way as with other publications, process your file as you usually would, and then insert the contents of the resulting `.bbl` file into your article.  You will need to find a BibTeX `.bst` file that matches the required style.

Comment: Have a look at [`IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf`](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf).